# Why does rendering a list of React Components in a Bootstrap Popover cause 'Invariant Violation'?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, reactjs

I'm rendering a 'Cart' component into a page's top level navigation element as below.

```
<li class='nav-borders-left cart-dropdown dropdownable'>
  <%= link_to image_tag('Icon-Cart.png'), '#', 'aria-haspopop' => 'true', 'aria-expanded' => 'false' %>
  <ul class="cart-content popover">
    <li>
      <%= react_component 'Cart', { data: { currentUserId: current_user.id } } %>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Then inside the cart component, I have a typical array of `Item` objects that are being rendered each into their own component as referenced below,

```
@Cart = React.createClass

  displayCart: ->
    React.DOM.div
      className: null
      className: 'data'
      React.DOM.div
        className: 'cart'
        React.DOM.div
          className: 'heading'
          React.DOM.div
            className: null
            React.DOM.img
              className: 'small-icon'
              src: '/assets/Icon-Cart.png'
            React.DOM.span
              className: null
              'Shopping Cart'
      for item, index in @state.items 
        uniqueKey = "#{item.productId}#{index}"
        React.createElement Item, key: uniqueKey, item: item, product: item.product
```

I'm giving the `Item` object a unique key that is after verification, unique.

I'm instantiating the actual popover with some rather unsavory code as I need to pretty precise control over the action, which I'm controlling through a standard java(coffee)script object as below,

```
class CartInterface
  constructor: () ->
    @content = '.cart-content'
    @popover = '.cart-dropdown'
    @initCartDisplay()
    @showCart()
    @hideCart()

  initCartDisplay: () ->
    $(@popover).popover(
      html: true
      placement: 'bottom'
      trigger: 'manual' 
      content: () ->
        $(@).children('.cart-content').html()
      )

  showCart: () ->
    $(@popover).click (e) =>
      popoverIsHidden = $('.popover').is(':visible') == false
      if popoverIsHidden
        $(@popover).popover('show')

  hideCart: () ->
    $('body').click (e) =>
      clickOutsideContent = $(e.target).parents('.popover-content').length == 0
      cartDropDownParents = $(e.target).parents('.cart-dropdown')
      notShowClick = cartDropDownParents.length == 0
      popoverIsShown = $('.popover').is(':visible')
      if notShowClick && clickOutsideContent && popoverIsShown
        $(@popover).popover('hide')

new CartInterface
```

Barring any problems with the `CartInterface` object, the general pattern is that the top level navigation element renders an icon, when that icon is clicked, if the popover is not current displayed, display it and then once the popover is displayed, if the user clicks anywhere outside the popover, close the popover.

My problem, upon rendering the `Item` objects, note, any point of 'mouseover' the cart element (not on page load), chrome coughs up a series of errors that look (and smell) like,

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.0.0
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.0.0
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.0.0.0
2react-a1e4ef4f52c95eebf22e958a0fe4af2c.js?body=1:20303 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .0.0.0.0.1
```

I'm generally thinking that there may be a problem with the content of the popover not being accurately reflected in the real DOM when React does its thing and then when the popover gets rendered, react maybe having trouble accounting for the new or what it might consider to be 'extra' dom nodes.

It would probably stand to reason that I should mention, the `Cart` component is basically being instantiated with an empty `.items` state, ie `[]` and on `componentDidMount`, I'm calling to the server to get the current user's items in question, then updating the state, which should be triggering a re-render.

Any help in understanding either how to get more context related to the why of this error or just general trouble shooting help would be appreciated.  I'm reasonably new to react, < 3weeks in, but it is a sharp tool that I appreciate though my usage of it might be problematic.

Thanks,

JD